# What is the standard practice to serve a REST API request, based on requester format?

Tags: json, rest, api

In my REST API, I have an `/items/` endpoint which returns a list of items.

The user of my API may request the items in different formats (json, xml, html).

What is the recommended way to provide a json response:

- make an `/items.json` endpoint ?
- make an `/items/json` endpoint ?
- or serve it based on user's request header `Content-Type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve it based on the `Accept` request header. This is a standard practice called [*content type negotiation.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)